# Is it ok for Angular Directives to have Service Dependencies?

Tags: angular

I'm contemplating wether to make an angular directive witch calls a project service as a dependency. I wanted to hear other opinions. Is it ok to do this? Is there a special folder convention for organizing these files? Right now I have my services and directives in separate folders in /src/app as:

/src/app/services  <- dependency is in here
/src/app/directives

Comment: Short answer: it's OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is okay. Services are to be used in any part of the app.